# GnuWin32 sed not replacing lines in a file

Tags: windows, sed, cmd

I was testing the sed utility with a txt file with a single line

```
PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=1
```

I used the following pattern but is not replacing the line within the file. but it is not really the line.

```
H:\sed.exe -e "s/@PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=1/@PJL COMMENT
PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=2/g" H:\test.txt H:\test.txt
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do the `@` mean? Leave them out.

And don't replace the file on it selve.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tichodroma, either use '/' or '@' as your regex delimiter, not both. When you include '@' in the search target string, it has to be in the file to make a match.

More importantly, why do you repeat the filename at the end of the `sed` cmd?

Either you want

```
H:\sed.exe -e "s/PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=1/PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=2/g" H:\test.txt > H:\test2.txt
```

OR if your sed supports the -i option,

```
H:\sed.exe -i "s/PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=1/PJL COMMENT PREPRINTINFO : COPIES=2/g" H:\test.txt
```

The 'g' at the end of your command means 'global' and is probably redundant, so to make your code as efficient as possible, you should remove it, unless you expect any 1 line of text to contain more than one copy of your search target. I have left it in place, as you may be doing more with your files than your question indicates.

Finally, `-e` doesn't add much to a sed command, AND it will mess up the use if `-i`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "Finally, `-e` doesn't add much to a sed command, AND it will mess up the use if `-i`". This is the first time I heard about such thing. Say no to cargo cult; read the man page instead.